# HTTPcontext not returning correct result

Tags: c#, http, httpcontext

I am trying to fetch the current user name using HTTPcontext object using

```
string username=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

but I am observing weird behavior i.e. when I load first time I get username as `NT AUTHORITY\IUSR`
but when I load second or third time I get the correct logged in username. Couldn't figure out why on first run correct username is not getting returned.

Comment: Where did you check username ? In which method.

Comment: As soon as I load the application there is a method fetchdata() inside this method I am fetching logged in username.

Comment: ASP.net or ASP.net MVC. Do you write method global.asax ?

Comment: C#, it has a MVC pattern

Comment: Try to use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name. See if this and httpcontext both return same result

Answer (score 1):

This ia actually a **feature** called **ASP.NET Impersonation**. which is enabled for your application.

In this instance, ASP.NET impersonates the token passed to it by IIS, which is either an authenticated user or the anonymous Internet user account (IUSR_machinename). That is what exactly happening to your application. 
you can read about Impersonation and how to control it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).